# Init script doesn’t work properly by using “service” command

Tags: service, upstart, gnu-screen

I have the following startup script, which should either start or stop a screen in detached mode:

```
#!/bin/sh

# node2
# Maintainer: @KittBlog
# Authors: mk@kittmedia.com

### BEGIN INIT INFO
# Provides:          node2
# Required-Start:    $local_fs $remote_fs $network $syslog
# Required-Stop:     $local_fs $remote_fs $network $syslog
# Default-Start:     2 3 4 5
# Default-Stop:      0 1 6
# Short-Description: node2 in screen detached mode
# Description:       node2 in screen detached mode
# chkconfig: - 85 14
### END INIT INFO
NODE_NAME=node2
SCREEN=$(which screen)
SCRIPT_PATH=/home/jail/

do_start() {
    if !($SCREEN -r | grep -o "[0-9]*\.$NODE_NAME"); then
        $SCREEN -S $NODE_NAME -d -m $SCRIPT_PATH/start-npm.sh
    fi
}

do_stop() {
    for session in $($SCREEN -r | grep -o "[0-9]*\.$NODE_NAME"); do
        $SCREEN -S "${session}" -X quit
    done
}

case "$1" in
    start|stop)
        do_$1
        ;;
    restart)
        do_stop
        do_start
        ;;
    *)
        echo "Usage: $0 {start|stop|restart|status}"
        exit 1
        ;;
esac
exit 0
```

It works properly if I start the script manually or if I use it by calling `/etc/init.d/node2 {start|stop|restart}`.

Also using `service node2 start` works fine except that the if clause is getting ignored, so that there is always a new screen detached even if there already is one.

The problem is that `service node2 stop` doesn’t work. I know that `service` runs the script in a “predictable environment”. Is that a problem here? Can’t I use the `$SCREEN -r | grep -o "[0-9]*\.$NODE_NAME"` in order to determine if there already is an active screen in this environment?

Comment: try to replace "#!/bin/sh" with "#!/bin/sh -x" and re-run script via service. Output may help you to resolve your issue.

Comment: Unfortunately, there is no output. Neither on `service node2 start` nor on `service node2 stop`.

Comment: Also upstart logs your service execution in a log file by the same name in /var/log/upstart/your-service-name.log. It should be helpful.

Comment: Use "$SCREEN -ls " in order to determine if there already is an active screen in this environment

Comment: `$SCREEN -ls`worked well, thank you! If you write this as answer I will mark it as correct. By the way: There is no `/var/log/upstart` in Debian, which I’m using.

Comment: Which version of Debian are you using?

Comment: The latest stable one, Debian 8.5.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According [manpage](https://www.gnu.org/software/screen/manual/screen.html) use $SCREEN -ls in order to determine if there already is an active screen in this environment. If there is no logs of your script in /var/log/upstart then try to add debug info in your script